# How to safely access actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues if the key is not found?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am currently doing this, but it throws an exception if the key is not found.

This snippet is inside of a web api filter that inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute`, in the overriden method `OnActionExecuting`.

```
if (actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("some_key") != null 
                && actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("some_key").First() == "hello")
{

}
```

Am I forced to wrap this in a try/catch?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
class MyFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> values;
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("some_key", out values) && values.First() == "hello")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, there is no indexer in System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext

Comment: @user1361315 I'm a little confused where you're getting the Request out of the context, but I've written out the full attribute for you.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Oneliner if you want... if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("some_key", out IEnumerable<string> values) && values.First() == "some_key") { }

Answer (score 4):

Since the release of C# 6.0, here is an alternative syntax to Yuriy Faktorovich's answer where you will get the header value or null as a result in a single line.

`actionContext.Request.Headers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "some_key").Value?.First()`